# Convert decimal to date format SQL

Tags: sql, date, casting, decimal, to-date

I am trying to convert a column FC_FROM_DATE containing decimal values (ex. 20,200,721) into a date format 2020/07/21.

I have tried this code

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CHAR(CAST(FC_FROM_DATE AS DECIMAL(8,0))), 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
FROM MARKETS.FORECAST
```

I get an error

> Argument for chr should be between 0 and 127

Would much appreciate your help!

Comment: Is this Sql Server?

Comment: Is `FC_FROM_DATE` a varchar or a decimal in the source schema?

Comment: @Igor yes it's Sql, and I believe it's a decimal in the source schema

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, sql-server, mysql...?

Comment: @GMB I am using sql in Exasol. I believe it's MySQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change decimal to date format MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182163/change-decimal-to-date-format-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(FC_FROM_DATE AS VARCHAR(8), 'YYYY/MM/DD') FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the persisted format is `YYYYMMDD` you could convert the value to a `varchar(8)` and then use `CONVERT` to get a `Date` instance.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(FC_FROM_DATE AS VARCHAR(8))) FROM MARKETS.FORECAST
```

Ideally Dates are stored as Date and a Date with a time component is stored as DATETIME2 (or equivalent if not Sql Server).

#### Test of the code above

```
DECLARE @FC_FROM_DATE decimal(8,0) =  20200721
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(@FC_FROM_DATE AS VARCHAR(8)))
```

> 2020-07-21

*Disclaimer: This works in MS Sql Server.*

Comment: I got this error: *'data exception - invalid character value for cast; Value: '20200702' Format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' in cast of expression CAST(FORECAST.FC_FROM_DATE AS VARCHAR(8) UTF8)'*

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I still get an error though, how would that work for MySQL?

Comment: `how would that work for MySQL` ← I do not know @mromankim, that is why I asked if you were using Sql Server (what Microsoft calls their product) to which you responded "yes". You should always tag your question with the RDBMS you need the answer for and when you tagged `sql` there was a tooltip that also made you are of this.

Comment: Thanks @Igor for the clues. I am super new to sql and didn't know that there would be a difference.

Comment: @mromankim update your question and add the correct MySQL tag off you want an answer from someone on the community.

Comment: @mromankim - my adding the [tag:MySql] your question will appear in the question feeds of those that like to answer MySql specific questions. By not doing that it might not show up on their feed and the rest of the community still does not immediately see what RDBMS you are using and provide an answer that does not work for MySql.